# Javascript remove Regex Delimiter

Tags: php, javascript, regex, json

My code in PHP generate a JSON based on the user input.

Inside this JSON, I have a Regex string "/regex/gi" with the delimiter.

I send this to the user and I would like javascript to test a string based on that regex. But since I have the delimiter inside the string, it does not work.

Sometime, I can receive the regex string as "regex", "/regex/" or "/regex/gi"
So is there a way to remove thoses delimiter, or transform the string in a regex.

I tried to use "new RegExp" but it escape the string, and it won't work.

Here some code:

```
var json = {regex: "/hello/"}; //This code is generated by PHP
"hello".match(json.regex); //Test in javascript, not working, since the "/" are inside the regex and not used as delimiter
```

Anyone have an idea how I could do this?

Thank

Comment: code sample will be useful.

Comment: Some code pls, we neeed to see

Comment: @balajimca var json = { regex: "/hello/" } //Generated by php, "hello".match(json.regex); //Not working, only work if the string is "/hello/"

Comment: bro, Can you update your question with your code. Not in comment section :)

Comment: You should accept **one** format, otherwise you will bump into problems. I'll show you an example: user1 tries `/\/\//`, user2 tries `/\/\//gi` and user3 `\/\/` (without delimiters). If we removed the `/` from the begin and the end, the third user will have a problem.

Comment: @HamZa At first, I was thinking of removing the first and last char if they are the same, but your example is why it won't work... even more, if the user enter a word like "test" it will remove the "t"

Answer (score 2):

You could regex your regex (woah)

```
var reMeta = /(^|[^\\])\/(\w+$){0,1}/;
var json = {regex: "/hello\/slash\//gi"};

json.regex = new RegExp( json.regex.replace(reMeta,'$1') );
// after replace it looks like: "hello\/slash\/"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var json = {regex: "/hello/"};

"hello".match(eval(json.regex));//Simle way (bad practice, but will work)
```

More propel way:

```
var json = {regex: "hello"};
var reg = new RegExp(json.regex)
var matched = reg.exec("hello") != null;
```

Comment: I would highly prefer not to use eval. I tried the new RegExp class, but if the input is "/hello/" RegExp will escape the "/", I need a way to simply remove them.